# Flexbox - Horizontal component with full height squared image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to achieve what seems to be a very easy task with flexbox, but after hours, I fail...

I just want to create a **responsive** horizontal component with **an image on the left** who always be `100%` height and some flexible width **text on the right**.

Should be easy, but the image never stops overlapping in the best case...

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card {
  background: #F1F1F2;
  display: flex;
}

.card-img {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.card-body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some amazing content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it is impossiple to make the right div have same height with the image because:
The `height` of the right div depend on it's `witdh`. Because of the parent div has fixed `width` so the `width` of the right div depend on the left div's `width`. The left div `width` depend on the image `height`. So when you change image `height`, the right div `height` change too. Now, i think the best way is give the image a `fixed` size.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card {
  background: #F1F1F2;
  display: flex;
}

.card-img {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 130px;
  width: auto;
}

.card-body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some amazing content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.card-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}
.card-grid-img img{
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}
.card-grid-body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-grid">
  <div class="card-grid-img">
    <img src="http://www.salavaux.ch/222/5_sq.jpg" alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card-grid-body">
    <h4 class="card-grid-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-grid-text">Some amazing content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Some amazing content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using grid you could then add a constraint on height first column elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using a minimal width for the image container.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card {
  background: #F1F1F2;
  display: flex;
}

.card-img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-width: 130px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.card-body {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some amazing content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you just need to add flex property to .card-img

You can learn more about flex property here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card {
  background: #F1F1F2;
  display: flex;
}

.card-img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex; //just add this line
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.card-body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some amazing content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never add `display: flex;` on direct image parent. This will break the ratio in almost any cases.